# SSIS Connection manager issue

Tags: sql-server, excel, ssis, dataflow, ssis-connection-manager

I created a Project within SSIS it would take data from a table within a db, do a data conversion and then insert into a Excel spreadsheet. it was working fine with no issues for about a week but now I'm having issues with th e connection manager. I'm getting the data fine from the DB its when it comes to the excel spreadsheet. I have tried doing the project again but still doesn't work. I create a new excel destination within SSIS > a new connection manager go to folder destination and state what I want document to be called. nothing is available from the name of excel sheet drop down and when I select NEW it just closes window. I'm not sure what has gone wrong is it a permissions thing? I have attached screenshot of this and the error when I run application
[image]

error when deploy application
[image]

Comment: Do you have permissions to write to that folder, try creating connection manager to your local c drive and check

Comment: Does the excel file still exist?

Comment: In The Excel Connection Manager Properties, Try changing the delay validation property. It worked for me when I had the same issue. 

Also, Make sure that the destination file is not open in any other programmes

Comment: I have tried having the connection manager look at a folder on network drive and C drive and still does do it....I have tried creating spreadsheet before connection manager and have tried creating through connection manager. I just don't understand what has happened as it has been working in the past

Comment: Can you try the same with import export wizard and check please

Comment: have tried with import export wizard and still no luck

Comment: Where it is failing on Import export wizard, can u add a screen shot please

Answer (score 1):

i think something must have changed with access to the db. if I use the import wizard and select  OLE DB for SQL server as the Datasource nothing is appearing in the server name drop down and If I manual enter it I get an error

[image]

Answer (score -1):

Try this:
Step 1)  Navigate to Project-> [PROJECT_NAME] Properties.
Step 2:  Navigate to “Debugging” option from left panel and from Right panel change **Run64BitRuntime** value to **false**.

Comment: He is not even able to establish connection manager, changing run time for failure of package execution